# How to modify an O(n) list length function to run in O(1)?

Tags: c, memory, data-structures, big-o

From this link, is a copy of the file ilist.c
http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs136/assignments/a5/

What i need to do is how to convert this O(n) function to run in O(1):

```
// computes the number of elements in il
int ilength(ilist il)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (!iempty_huh(il))
    {
        i++;
        il = irest(il);
    }
    return i;
}
```

I can edit functions in the ilist.c file (im assuming the struct and icons) but i can't edit the ilist.h file. I don't know how to approach the conversion to O(1) at all, any ideas, would be helpful !

Comment: `int ilength(ilist il){ return 42; } // there, O(1)`

Comment: if i add a struct, to simplfy it... point to number of nodes or something?

Comment: you don't need a pointer.  But yes, you need to modify the struct.

Comment: Why the <beep> doesn't anyone format code anymore? Code is for humans, and the fact that post your homework here only proves that!

Comment: I've rolled back the question text as your last edit made no sense. Please leave the original text of the question intact - that way it may help others seeking the same answer (it also keeps answers in context).

P.S. If one of the answers helped you solve the question, please mark it as such!

Comment: Just a small side note: I don't really see why you use int type. For a strictly size figure, you'd be better off with an unsigned type, such as unsigned int or size_t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct ilist_node {
    struct ilist_node * rest;
    int first;
    int length; //new field!
};
```

Functions to change accordingly: `icons`, `ilength`.

Comment: more discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2560136#2560136)

Answer (score 6):

You can just store the number of the elements in the list in the object associated with it, increase it with every added element, and decrease it with every deleted element. Then, if the total length of the list is requested, you just return that number.

I don't see any other way of doing that. Traversal of a linked list **always** requires O(n).

Comment: Actually, it's simpler than that, because of how the list is implimented.

Answer (score 2):

As a hint, what if you updated the list so that it precomputes the length whenever you do an operation on it?  That way, you could have the length just return the precomputed value in O(1).

Answer (score 2):

The key is that you are allowed to store extra information behind the interface in ilist.h - think about *maintaining* a count of elements as a part of the list as you add and remove them. Then just return the count for ilength.

Answer (score 2):

If you keep track of the size of ilist when you build it you can just return the already known size in O(1).